# Web Deploy: how do I include specific files in a webdeploy package?

Tags: webdeploy

1. I am transitioning my web application solution from xcopy deployment to Web Deploy deployment.
2. I have a PostBuild action that generates files the web app needs at runtime.
3. I want to use the 'Only files needed to run this application' option.

The generated files are, of course, not in the solution - which means that they don't get picked up by the setting above (which I want to use in order to avoid a long, long, ugly list of files-to-exclude).  I know that [there's a way to exclude files and folders explicitly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-application-s-project-file.aspx), but is there a way to *include* files explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi would seem to disagree with the current answer.

http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx

According to this article you can modify the project file / create your own targets file that will include a specific file or folder by tying into the current build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

No such mechanism exists.  The best practice is to set up the aforementioned long list of exclusions, and use the "all files" option.